# Iterator says arbitrary behaviour

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator

The last line in the following section says https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#accessing-values-in-a-hash-map :

> This code will print each pair in an arbitrary order

It says Iter visits all KVs in arbitrary order. What does arbitrary mean, why is this order so indeterministic, and/or is this really the case, what is the possible reason for this?

Why does the standard library have such an implementation and how does it work under the hood, I need clarity over the working of Iter.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered maybe reading the book?

> What does the "Some" prefix signify?

[It’s not a “prefix”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html).

> Does it have any use?

`pop()` returns an option because there could be nothing to return if the collection is empty.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid since the OP completely modified their question.